# Laravel - How does a FormRequest differ from a Request?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5, request

Certain fields do not send when using a FormRequest. In a project I had to use some custom validation on a potentially unlimited array of inputs:

```
<input type="file" name="image[1]" />
<input type="file" name="image[2]" />
```

etc...

To validate these I created a FormRequest called StoreProject:

```
public function rules()
{

    $rules = [

        'title' => 'required',

    ];

    foreach( $this->request->get( 'image' ) as $key => $val )
    {

        $rules['image.'.$key] = 'image';

    }

    return $rules;

}
```

In my controller function, I noticed a difference in what was sent via the request.

If my controller looks like like this:

```
public function store(StoreProject $request)
{

    dd( $request->all() );

}
```

None of my array inputs are included in the request. Whereas if I use the standard Request like so.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    dd( $request->all() );

}
```

My array inputs appear fine.

Does anyone know why this might be? Or how I can still access these images whilst still using my custom validation?

Answer (score 1):

You can validate arrays with the `*` operator:

```
public function rules()
{    
    return [    
        'title' => 'required',
        'image.*' => 'image',
    ];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files

`$request->all()` doesn't contain uploaded file inputs. You must use:
`$request->file('image')` method or `$request->image` dynamic property.

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer in your question.

`Illuminate\Http\Request` - can be used directly

but

`Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest` - needs to be extended with a class that would have implementation for `rules()` and `authorize()` functions

Also

`Illuminate\Http\Request` - is a singleton, you will get it anywhere by running a function `request()`. It is initiated in your `\public\index.php` file.